# No puedo hacer login en un FTP desde Java (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, ftp

Estoy intentando hacer login en un ftp desde Spring, pero por más que pruebo recibo el error:

> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@PostMapping("/upload") public void uploadFile(
        @RequestParam(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception{
    
    //Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    final String host = env.getProperty("ftp.host");
    final String user = env.getProperty("ftp.user");
    final String password = env.getProperty("ftp.password");
    
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    
    if(multipartFile == null || multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("Elige un archivo válido");
    }
    
    
    try {
        
        ftpClient.connect(host);
        
        int connectionReply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        
        if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(connectionReply)) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido conectar. El servidor FTP respondió con el código " + connectionReply);
        }
        
        
        boolean loginOk = ftpClient.login(user, password);
        
        if(loginOk) {
            System.out.println("Login correcto");
        }else {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido hacer login en el servidor FTP");
        }
        
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
        
        for(FTPFile file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
        
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();          
                    
    } catch(IOException e) {
        
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

He hecho un println de las credenciales y son las que deben ser. Las he probado en FileZilla y conecta sin problemas.

Por si sirve de algo, el error salta en la línea:

```
boolean loginOk = ftpClient.login(user, password);
```

...pero he buscado en internet y no encuentro una causa para este caso.

Un saludo!

Comment: cuál es tu servidor de ftp? podrías adicionar esta información al post.

Comment: Puede que debas usar passive mode para conectarte, por ejemplo.

Comment: Hola! Mi servidor ftp es ondemand-test-xxx.streaming-pro.com. Las "xxx" son el nombre de la empresa para la que trabajo. Por otro lado, he probado a mover la línea del "passive mode" antes del login, pero no ha servido. Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho probar y probar, incluso con otras librerías, he vuelto a FTPClient y he conseguido resolver el problema.

Lo primero, que me ha llevado a la respuesta, ha sido añadir esta línea:

```
ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
```

De esta forma, puedo ver en consola mensajes más detallados de lo que está ocurriendo, como lo vería en la consola de un cliente de ftp como FileZilla, por ejemplo.

Gracias a esto, he visto el siguiente error:

```
530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.
```

Y a raíz de ahí y con una pequeña búsqueda he averiguado que la solución pasaba por sustituir...

```
FTPClient
```

por...

```
FTPSClient
```

Ojalá esto le llegue a servir a alguien en algún momento, porque en mi caso ha sido mucha impotencia por no entender nada.